# RegexHow can i validate an underscore between letters

Tags: regex

How can i allow any word character and the underscore should have a letter and a number between it.

example: ab2_sb, s_s,

but it shouldn't allow sdc_ or _s2

this is my code

`[a-zA-Z0-9_]{6,255}$`

I'm using regex on javascript

Answer (score 5):

You need to separate the character length check from the pattern and do not forget anchors if not added implicitly:

```
^(?=.{6,255}$)[a-zA-Z0-9]+(?:_[a-zA-Z0-9]+)*$
```

If there can only be 1 underscore, replace the last `*` with `?` quantifier.

**Details**:

- `^` - start of string
- `(?=.{6,255}$)` - a length check, 6 to 255 chars other than line break symbols
- `[a-zA-Z0-9]+` -  1 or more alphanumeric chars
- `(?:_[a-zA-Z0-9]+)*` - zero or more occurrences of:

  - `_` - an underscore
  - `[a-zA-Z0-9]+` - 1 or more alphanumeric chars
- `$` - end of string.

Comment: That's the one!

Comment: Thanks alot @Wiktor

Answer (score 1):

What about:

```
([a-zA-Z]+_?[a-zA-Z]+)*
```

This ensures that anytime an underscore appears it must be surrounded by at least 1 character on either side.

Comment: But you forgot the {6,225} constraint, which makes this hard (and is why I upvoted the question).

Comment: Thanks alot @jackarms